# Dynamic Routing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I've used this routing in localhost and it works fine:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But when I deploy to a server with this structure:

```
servername/folder/Controller/Action
```

the styles and the pages get 404 error.

I want to change the routing dynamically between localhost and server

Comment: What does your folder structure look like on localhost?  What does it look like on the server?

Comment: the estructures are the same. I've just desploy the solution in the same server with this estructure servername/Controller/Action and it works fine. But I have to use this one: servername/folder/Controller/Action.

Comment: Then mirror that folder structure on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheets do not use routing they are in a set path that you set in the _layout If you want to set them dynamically you can use your web.config and do a transform to set the location based on the environment you are deploying to.

If you want to do dynamic routing then you need a placeholder, and you will need to supply the value at runtime. ***The files must exist in the physical path that matches the route***

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{servername}/{folder}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { servername = "servername", folder = "foldername", 
     controller = "authentication", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   };
```